# How to create Android Studio project with ONLY a library module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to create an Android Studio project with just a library module in it. If I go to File -> New -> New Project, it assumes that I'm making an app, even if I tell it not to create an empty activity. If I then make a library module, I'll have a useless `app` module in the project as well.

Is there any way to remove that module? I've tried deleting the directory (which seems to confuse Android Studio) and I've tried deleting it through the Module Settings menu in Android Studio (which causes it to be immediately recreated). There must be a way to do this, right?

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a project. See https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is having this same problem, it appears that you truly cannot delete the app module from an Android Studio project. All projects must have an app module, even if the main purpose is to create a library. I ended up making a small example app showing how to use the library, which appears to be the convention.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a module, which needs to be part of a project.

Feel free to delete the `app` module, or actually show example usage of your library, which is what most libraries provide

[From Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library)

> Create a library module
>
> To create a new library module in your project, proceed as follows:
>
> Click **File > New > New Module**
> In the Create New Module window that appears, click **Android Library**, then click Next.

Comment: Right, I've tried to delete the app module, but I can't find any way to do that. Do you know how it is possible to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove module from project structure;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't delete the App module, you convert it to a library per the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Convert.

In summary:

1. Open Android Studio (I'm on Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2),
2. New Project,
3. Phone and Tablet > "No Activity",
4. Fill out the new empty project details (I'm calling mine HelloJava),
5. Finish and wait for sync....
6. Select Project from the drop-down in the project pane to view the project files,
7. Expand "app", double click "build.gradle.kts",
8. Find the "plugins" section and convert "com.android.application" to "com.android.library".
9. Find the "defaultConfig" section, and remove lines for "applicationId", "versionCode", "versionName"

If you now build, you'll get an AAR instead of an APK.